# Published asp.net website not accessible in other system in same network

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web, iis-manager

I have developed a asp.net website and published in a server.Whereas everything works perfectly in that server if i give browser from that IIS manager, and in server ( published system ) everything works perfect.But i need to access the same published application also in the other systems also ( which are connected in same network ). How is it possible..??

**NOTE:**
1. Used IIS 7.

When tried to connect from another system from same networ getting error as follows

**The socket connection to 172.31.7.243 failed. 
ErrorCode: 10060.A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.31.7.243:90**

Answer (score 0):

If Your are accessing Your application on Hosted Server like this then just replace 
localhost with ipaddress of hosted server to access it over the network

```
[localhost]/MyProjectName
```

then like this:

```
[IPaddress_of_HostedServer]/MyProjectName
```

Comment: yep i tried and this is what working only in the published system.But not accessible for other systems in same network.Shows error The socket connection to 172.31.7.243 failed. 
ErrorCode: 10060.

Comment: so that client is able to ping hosted server ?? or may be any firewall ON on those clients??

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the HTTP traffic on port 80 incoming from the local network is blocked.

You should check if ISA server is installed on your server and if so if HTTP traffic on port 80 is allowed or not. If it's blocked try to allow it for the local network ip range.

Edit: Or port 90 as your error code states, but why are you working on port 90?